# Fetch value (integer) from SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

I have an integer in a SQL database, I am trying to find the value of that integer in php.
The integer is the number of likes of a photo. Here is my query:

```
$result = query("SELECT likes FROM NSPhotos WHERE IdPhoto='%s' LIMIT 1", $imageID);
```

How do I get the integer value out of "$results"?

Comment: Hi, this is very basic and broad - you are not specifying which database library you are using. You should probably work through a basic mySQL tutorial for your library.

Comment: be more specific are what are you using? mysqli or pdo? little more details would be needed

Comment: I believe I am using mysqli, I worked through a tutorial here:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using MySQL you would do something like:

```
// Establish a connection to the database
$mysqli = new mysql('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

$query = "SELECT likes FROM NSPhotos WHERE IdPhoto = ".$imageID." LIMIT 1";
$result= $mysqli -> query($query);
$num   = $mysqli -> num_rows;

if($num > 0){

   // Fetch the result from the database
   $row = $result -> fetch_object();

   // Print the result or you could put it in a variable for use later.
   echo 'Likes: '.$row -> likes;
   $like_count = $row -> likes;

}else{
   echo 'Photo not found.';

}
```

Comment: here is how I connect to the database, I don't think I am using MySQL,       $link = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass");
    mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name) or die("no database");

Comment: The way your connecting is through `mysqli` procedural style. The example i've given is in Object style.